# Problem using specific version of Kubernetes in Minikube

Tags: docker, minikube

I'm trying to launch a Minikube cluster in my local machine with the latest version of Kubernetes (`1.22.3` if I'm correct).
I run `minikube start --kubernetes-version=v1.22.3` and the binaries are not found with error:

```
Failed to update cluster: downloading binaries: downloading kubeadm: Error downloading kubeadm v1.22.3: failed to download: failed to download to temp file: failed to create validator: failed to create validator: failed to download checksum file: received status code 404
```

I've tested to change the command and use an older version `minikube start --kubernetes-version=v1.12.10` instead. This one works perfectly.

What am I doing wrong? If I'm correct that version (`1.22.3`) is already released. I've tested with versions in between, like around 1.19 and they are not working either.

Comment: It seems like the latest minikube has K8s's v1.22.3 set to be the [default](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/blob/master/pkg/minikube/constants/constants.go#L37). Are you running the latest version of minikube? What if you do not specify the version of kubernetes, what is being installed?

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you have an **older version of the minikube installer binary**. In order to check your version, run the following command:

```
minikube version
```

It should show you:

```
minikube version: v1.24.0
```

If it shows any older version, please go to [minikube website](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/start/) and download the latest **minikube installer binary** for your OS. For **Linux x86-64** architecture you can get and install it with the following commands:

```
curl -LO https://storage.googleapis.com/minikube/releases/latest/minikube-linux-amd64
sudo install minikube-linux-amd64 /usr/local/bin/minikube
```

Then you can simply run:

```
minikube start
```

which will set up kubernetes cluster with its default version, which for the current latest version of **Minikube** happens to be `v1.22.3`, so exactly the version you need. Or you can specify this version explicitly:

```
minikube start --kubernetes-version=v1.22.3
```

which will also work.